# How to rotate IAM user access keys

Tags: aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-java-sdk

I am trying to rotate the user access keys & secret keys for all the users, last time when it was required I did it manually but now I want to do it by a rule or automation

I went through some links and found this link 
https://github.com/miztiik/serverless-iam-key-sentry
with this link, I tried to use but I was not able to perform the activity, it was always giving me the error, can anyone please or suggest any better way to do it?

As I am new to aws lamda also I am not sure that how my code can be tested?

Comment: What error occurs and how did you test it? What is your code? Any example?

Comment: my code is big it does not fit here and i made only change change the owner name and region name to us-east-1 , no errors came , not sure why its not working

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to implements a solution. One common way you can automate this is through a storing the IAM user access keys in Secret Manager for safely storing the keys. Next, you could configure a monthly or 90 days check to rotate the keys utilizing the AWS CLI and store the new keys within AWS Secrets Manager. You could use an SDK of your choice for this.